# Prove $\sum\limits_{n\mathop=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{e^{2\pi}+1}{e^{2\pi}-1}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I show that

$$\sum\limits_{n\mathop=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{e^{2\pi}+1}{e^{2\pi}-1}\right)$$

Comment: See **ZZ**'s upvoted comment on [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736860/find-the-infinite-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-1).

Answer (score 3):

For example, using the [Poisson summation formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoissonSumFormula.html):
$$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(n)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(k),\qquad \hat{f}(\nu)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi i \nu x}dx.$$
Namely, setting $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$, we obtain
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\nu)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi i \nu x}dx}{x^2+1}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi i \nu x}dx}{x^2+1}=
\pi e^{-2\pi |\nu|},
\end{align}
where we calculated the last integral by residues. Therefore, we can write
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\pi\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-2\pi |k|}=\frac{\pi\sinh2\pi}{\cosh2\pi-1}=\pi \coth \pi.$$
This is obviously equivalent to the formula you want to prove.