# the partial fraction of ${\pi}\cot{\pi}z$ from the partial fraction of $\frac{\pi^{2}}{\sin^{2}{\pi}z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-fractions

I want to deduce the equation

$${\pi}\cot{\pi}z=\frac{1}{z}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2z}{z^{2}-n^{2}}$$

where the convergence is uniform on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{Z}$ from the partial fraction expression $\frac{\pi^{2}}{\sin^{2}{\pi}z}$. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: What's the derivative of $\pi \cot \pi z$?

Comment: It is $\frac{\pi^{2}}{sin^{2}{\pi}z}$, I have noticed that before and I tried to integrate the series term by term but I didn't get the right equation. Thank you.

Comment: In the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2\pi z}$, group the terms corresponding to $n$ and $-n$. Since you know where you want to arrive, that should help.

Comment: See **ZZ**'s upvoted comment on [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736860/find-the-infinite-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-1).