# Help with calculating infinite sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{1+n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on a problem, and I'm stuck in the calculations of finding

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2}$

Suggestions on how to approach this calculation? Thanks!

(Also, I used Fourier to get to this result from where we were... so using the Fourier somehow feels counter intuitive, but I might be wrong)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Hint :** Let $f(z) := \frac{1}{z^2+1}$. Note that $|z f(z)| \to 0$ as $|z| \to \infty$. Show that $g(z) := f(z) \cot \pi z$ has simple poles at $\pm i$ and that $\text{res}(g, \pm i) = - \frac{\pi \coth \pi}{2}$. Then conclude that the sum equals $\frac{\pi \coth \pi+1}{2}$

Comment: See also **ZZ**'s upvoted comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736860/find-the-infinite-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-1).

Comment: This question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666859/the-sum-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac1n23 is very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n^2+\alpha^2} = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2}+\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}\cdot\coth(\pi\alpha) \tag{1}$$
that holds for any $\alpha>0$, can be proved through the Weierstrass product for the sine function and the properties of the logarithmic derivative, just like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666859/the-sum-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac1n23/1666940#1666940). For instance, by considering that
$$ \lim_{\alpha\to 0^+}\left(-\frac{1}{2\alpha^2}+\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}\cdot\coth(\pi\alpha)\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\tag{2}$$
we may also easily compute $\zeta(2)$. Another approach for proving $(1)$ relies on:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{1}{n^2+1}\tag{3}$$
and the fact that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$ is the Fourier series of a [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), giving:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+1} = \frac{e^{2\pi}}{e^{2\pi}-1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\pi-x}{2}e^{-x}\,dx\tag{4} $$
from which:

> $$ \color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n^2+1}} = \frac{1+\pi\coth(\pi)}{2} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{e^{2\pi}+1}{e^{2\pi}-1}} \tag{5}$$

easily follows.