# The Sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know how to get the sum of geometric series, but otherwise.

How do I get the sum of this series?  Thank you.

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+3}$$

Comment: You've got $n$ as both a free and a bound variable.

Comment: You may want to look at the partial fraction decompositon of $\coth(z)$. For instance, see the formula 4.36.3 in http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36.

Comment: I've never seen the coth(z). Is there any other way to get the sum of this series?

Comment: Related post: [Find the infinite sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 +1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736860/find-the-infinite-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-1) some posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/736860) might be of interest, too.

Comment: @DannaDChoe Following on from Sangchul Lee's comment; the $\coth z$ relation is perfectly exhibited in these set of answers http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2

Comment: Here is more general version of your question: [Show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{a^2+n^2}=\frac{1+a\pi\coth a\pi}{2a^2}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2). Again, it might be worth having a look at [linked posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/208317), too.

Answer (score 12):

The Weierstrass product for the sine function gives:
$$ \forall z\in\mathbb{C},\quad\sin(z) = z\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2 \pi^2}\right)\tag{1} $$
hence by replacing $z$ with $iz$ we get:
$$ \forall z\in\mathbb{C},\quad\sinh(z) = \frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2} = z\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2 \pi^2}\right)\tag{2} $$
and by considering the logarithmic derivative, given by $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{d}{dz}\,\log f(z)$, we have:
$$ \forall z\in\mathbb{C},\quad\coth(z)=\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{e^{z}-e^{-z}}=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2z}{z^2+n^2\pi^2}\tag{3} $$
and by replacing $z$ with $\pi\sqrt{3}$ it follows that:
$$ \coth(\pi\sqrt{3})=\frac{e^{2\pi\sqrt{3}}+1}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{3}}-1}=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{3}}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2\pi\sqrt{3}}{\pi^2(n^2+3)}\tag{4} $$
so, by rearranging:

> $$ \color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n^2+3}}=\frac{1}{6}\left(1+\pi\sqrt{3}\coth(\pi\sqrt{3})\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{6}\cdot\frac{e^{2\pi\sqrt{3}}+1}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{3}}-1}}\approx 1.0736.\tag{5} $$

Another approach (a Fourier-analytic one) is shown [in this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742855/help-with-calculating-infinite-sum-sum-n-0-infty-frac11n2/1666961#1666961).