# How to calculate $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2}$

Tags: summation, proof-writing

How can I calculate the summation: $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2}$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the infinite sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 +1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736860/find-the-infinite-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-1)

Comment: and also of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/208317/

Comment: Differentiate the natural logarithm of [Euler's infinite product formula for the sine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Apply the Residue theorem for
$$f(z)=\frac{\pi\cot \pi z}{1+z^2}$$
using the circle at $0$ of radius $n+\frac12$ and take the limit.

Answer (score 4):

Using Fourier Series, [you can show that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left/110495#110495):

$$ \cot(\pi z) = \frac 1\pi \left( \frac 1z - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2z}{k^2 - z^2} \right) $$

Let $z = i$ to essentially get your sum, modulo some small simplifications which I'll leave to you.