# How to find the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that this particular series is convergent by the integral test 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+1}$$

how can one find the value to which it converges?

**Integral test:**

\begin{align*}
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+1} \ dx = \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{1}^{a} \frac{1}{x^2+1} = \lim_{a \to \infty}  \left[ \arctan(a) - \arctan(1) \right]= \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align*}

Comment: It's also convergent by the comparison test: It's smaller than $\sum1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$.

Comment: @Arthur I see thatyou have approached the "convergence test" in a different way. But is that a way to actually define, precisely, the value of that sum? (for example as a fraction, say 4/3)

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736860/find-the-infinite-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-1).

Comment: Good old [wolfie alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(n%5E2+%2B+1),+n+from+1+to+inf) says $\frac12\left(\pi\coth(\pi) - 1\right)$.

Comment: @Arthur Sure it follows from the partial fraction decomposition of trigonometric functions, eg. of $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, I see that it is not trivial at all!

Comment: $$\coth z=\frac{1}{z}+2z\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{2}+n^{2}\pi^{2}}$$ is formula 4.36.3 in [standard tables](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36).