# Calculate the amount of series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

We know that ‎$‎\sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎\frac{1}{k^2+1}‎ = ‎‎\frac{1}{2}(\pi ‎\coth‎(\pi) - 1)‎‎‎$‎‎. Now, how do we calculate the series‎ ‎$‎\sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎\frac{1}{(k + x)^2+1}‎$‎ for ‎‎$‎x\geq 0‎‎‎$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the infinite sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 +1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736860/find-the-infinite-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-1)

Comment: I won't say it's a duplicate, rather a generalization.

Comment: Thank you so much. Olivier Oloa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
 ‎\frac{2i}{(k + x)^2+1}&= ‎\frac{1}{k+x-i}-‎\frac{1}{k+x+i}
=\!\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+x+i}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+x-i}\right)
\end{align}
$$ yielding

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎\frac{1}{(k + x)^2+1}=\frac1{2i}\psi(x+1+i)-\frac1{2i}\psi(x+1-i),\qquad \text{Re}(x+1)>-1,\tag 1
> $$

where we have used the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula) which satisfy
$$
\psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(‎\frac{1}{k}-‎\frac{1}{k+z} \right),\quad \text{Re}z>-1.\tag2
$$
For example, by putting $x=\frac12$ in $(1)$, using special values of $\psi$, one gets

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎\frac{1}{\left(k + \frac12\right)^2+1}=\color{blue}{-\frac45+\frac \pi2 \tanh (\pi)}.\tag3
> $$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736860/find-the-infinite-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-1

Comment: @ Olivier Oloa, Hi, I have question that is : I work on a subject which required your closed form mentioned in (1). I  use (1) in some inequalities and I want to know that is (1) real or not because of (i)? thanks.

Comment: @soodehMehboodi If $x$ is a real number, then both sides of $(1)$ are real. Observe that, in this case $$\frac1{2i}\psi(x+1+i)-\frac1{2i}\psi(x+1-i)=\Im\left[\psi(x+1+i)\right]$$ which is a real number, as $x$ is a real number.

Comment: @ Olivier Oloa, Excuse me, would you tell me : how can you  prove that (1) is real. moreover,  what is the function on the right hand of  identity mentioned in your comment? thanks

Comment: @soodehMehboodi If $x$ is a real number, then each $\displaystyle ‎\frac{1}{(k + x)^2+1}$, $k=1,2,\cdots,$ is a real number, then $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎\frac{1}{(k + x)^2+1}$ is a real number, as a sum of real numbers. The related function is the digamma function $\psi$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function.

Comment: @ Olivier Oloa, Thanks a lot.