# $\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{1}{n^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, summation

I was trying to figure out $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{n^4-1}$ and I got $$\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{1}{n^2+1}$$
As a part of it, I've tied to solve it using partial fractions with complex numbers with no success.
Do any of you know how to derive the solution?(I got $\frac{1}{2}(1+\pi\coth(\pi))$ from wolfram alpha)

Comment: http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36.E3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the infinite sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 +1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736860/find-the-infinite-sum-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-1) Found using Approach0.

Comment: Yes, I've tried searching, I'm unsure why I didn't find it.